# What is the difference between the games in the Hacker Evolution series?

Tags: hacker-evolution-series

From the YouTube movies, they seem pretty similar. Is there anyone who can list the differences between Evolution, Evolution: Untold, and Evolution: Duality?

Comment: Duality is completely different (and inferior, if you measure it as a game about hackers).